# Radio Button Validation Error Message

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a message to display if neither radio button is displayed.  I have been researching the topic for awhile but haven't found an answer that worked for me.

Could someone explain what's wrong with my code and what is preventing the message from showing when neither check box is checked?

**CODE**

```
 <h2 class = "preferences">Preferences</h2>
 <form class="fifthForm">
   <p class="special">E-Mail Special Offers:</p>
   <input id="offersOne" type="radio" name="offers" value="Yes">Yes
   <input id="offersTwo" type="radio" name="offers" value="No">No
   <p id="preferenceResult"></p>
 </form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
try {
  var prefname = document.getElementsByName("offers");
  if (prefname[0].checked == false && prefname[1].checked == false) {
    throw "* Please choose a preference!";
  }
}
catch(prefError) {
  document.getElementById('preferenceResult').innerHTML = prefError;
}
```

Comment: Check this working JSFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/c2y25uwe/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, a return false; was executing in the statement prior to this one.  I ended up with similar code and removed the return false; so that the rest of the code would execute.

```
  try {
      var prefname = document.getElementsByName("offers");

      if (prefname[0].checked == false && prefname[1].checked == false) {
        throw "* Please choose a preference!";
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById('prefResult').innerHTML = "";
      }
    }
    catch(prefError) {
      document.getElementById('prefResult').innerHTML = prefError;
}
```